# $http put in AngularJs to WebApi call passing object one property as null

Tags: c#, angularjs, webapi

I am new to AngularJS. I created a dialog to update the one class object. All other properties are coming correctly except Id property.

Class:

```
 [Serializable]
public class Payment
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string PaymentId{ get; set; }

    public virtual string FeeType { get; set; }

    public virtual string Payer { get; set; }

    public virtual string Receiver { get; set; }
 
}
```

AngularJs Service

```
 var updatePaymentData = function (payment) {
        return serviceBase
            .put(serviceBase.applicationServiceWebApiUrl + "api/ExportMaintenance/UpdatePayment", payment)
            .then(function (result) {
                loggingManager.logSuccessMessage("payment " + payment.feeType + " has been updated.");

                return result;
            });
    };
```

ServiceBase Put code:

```
   function httpRequestWithTimeOut(req, timeOut) {
        var timeOutLength = timeOut;
        var hasTimeOut = false;
        var timeout = $q.defer();
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        setTimeout(function () {
            hasTimeOut = true;
            timeout.resolve();
        }, (1000 * timeOutLength));

        // Add the default timeout promise.
        req.timeout = timeout.promise;

        $http(req)
            .success(function (result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                if (hasTimeOut) {
                    deferred.reject({
                        error: "timeout",
                        message: "The request took too long and has time out."
                    });
                } else {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                }
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    } 


 var put = function (location, data) {
        var req = {
            method: "put",
            url: location,
            data: data,
            cache: false
        };

        return httpRequest(req);
    };
 function httpRequest(req) {
        // Default time out to 180 seconds.
        return httpRequestWithTimeOut(req, 180);
    }
```

WEB API related code:

```
  // PUT api/ExportMaintenance/UpdatePayment
    [HttpPut, ValidateModel]
    [WebApiClaimsAuthorization(Type = "ExportMaintenance", Value = "CanUpdate", Description = "Can update Export Maintenance")]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdatePayment(Payment paymentData)
    {
        var responseMessage = new ResponseMessage(Request, paymentData);

        _paymentBusinessLogic.UpdatePaymentData(paymentData, User, responseMessage);

        return responseMessage.SetHttpResponseMessage(paymentData);
    }
```

[image]

data object image in put request

[image]

They are some more properties in the Class I removed them while writing all properties are shown in data object image
request payload from network tab

[image]

Here in WebAPI I am getting payment.Id as null but when I see in chrome debug tools paymentData have Id value in Controller and service.

I am not able to understand why Id is coming as null. Please help me atleast how to analyse this issue.

Thanks,
Nagasree.

Comment: check your payload of request. in network tab of browser. And show the `payment` value before send request. (via console.log)

Comment: Hi I checked request Payload it doesn't have the Id Property.

Comment: Ok that means your client does not send id correctly. Trace your JavaScript code to see where you've missed id

Comment: And sow the `data` value in put function

Comment: data value in httpreq have id property with value

Comment: share the data here please

Comment: In put function you called `httpRequest` where is that? And when you call `httpRequestWithTimeOut`?

Comment: Hi Alireza I have added httpRequest method and the images from developer tool

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235245/discussion-between-alireza-ahmadi-and-nagasree).

Comment: Have you tried this header: 
`var req = {
method: "put",
url: location,
data: data,
headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"},
cache: false
};`

Comment: Yes Alireza Ahmadi. Still  Id value is null

Comment: if you sure payload does not have `id` your problem is in client side. So you can add your client code as runnable le snippet here to explore that

Comment: And also send sample data too

Comment: Hi Alireza The issue got resolved when I changed the property name of ID to guid in the c# class.

Comment: Congratulations. Oh yes. you know each JavaScript object has own `id` parameter and they had conflict with each other

Comment: Thanks.. I didn't  know it.so Javascript filter uid and ID properties?